# Is it a bad idea for user-uploaded images to have predictable file names? Or should they be randomly generated?

Tags: php, image, security, upload

I want to let users upload images, and my plan was to just name the image file after their username for easy reference. But it occurred to me that most websites which allow image uploading usually generate a random string of numbers for the name of the file. Is there any (security) advantage to doing this? Or is it just an unrelated decision by the developers?

For me, the advantage of using the username is that I don't need to store the string of numbers in the database for each user, and can reference images by username alone.

Answer (score 3):

The primary security concern is "information leaking". For instance, if your users have the option of not being publicly visible, an attacker who guesses your naming convention can retrieve a photo of a "hidden" user; this is probably not what the user wants.

Using a numerical filename - starting at "1.jpg", and incrementing - leaks other information; anyone can find out how many users you have by requesting files incrementally, and seeing when they get a 404 error.

From a software design point of view, you don't want to use your username as a primary key in many cases - usernames could change, for instance (esp. if you use email address as username). Your database primary key should be some immutable, unique thing, like a (G)(U)UID. This may well be the filename you see when looking at other sites' user photos.

Of course, if you allow users to upload more than one photo, using the primary key also doesn't work - so then you have to choose between "convention" - e.g. having a photo folder for each user, with some kind of way of finding out how many images are in that folder, or by explicitly storing those image paths in your database. In both cases, using the primary key to your user is probably insufficient...

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a namespacing issue, I believe.

The hosts which randomise the URL (that I know of) allow uploads without a user account - so your approach wouldn't work. Using a randomised folder/file naming minimises collisions of people uploading the same filename twice.

If you never need to accept anonymous uploads, I'd say it's up to personal preference how you organise user files and avoid namespace collisions...

Comment: That's a good point. But I've noticed it on other sites like Facebook, or even Gravatar which hosts the avatars here on SO. But I think both of those have issues way beyond the scope of what I'm working with. But yeah, I think you're mainly right. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest - go for what gives you uniqueness. For example - If I am about to upload my profile picture, I will probably name it like `me.jpg` and next time I log in, I expect my photo to look at me from the screen, the name of pic is not relevant to me *as user*

So if you do rename it to `Pavel_Janicek_me.jpg` or `dflw00axxwe.jpg` It really does not matter. As long as you show picture of myself.

If you allow users to upload more than one picture, consider some numbering. The renaming should solve you these errors:

- Two different users upload picture with exactly same name
- One user uploads two different pictures with same name